# How to change the selection in a TreeView on ContextMenu opening

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

If a right click is performed on a TreeItem in a TreeView, it will be selected. But if a right click is performed on another item while the context menu is open, the selection will not be updated.
[image: initial right click]
[image: second right click]

What can be done to update the selection on a second right click?

Comment: consumeAutoHidingEvents
public final BooleanProperty consumeAutoHidingEventsProperty
Specifies whether the event, which caused the Popup to hide, should be consumed. Having the event consumed prevents it from triggering some additional UI response in the Popup's owner window.
Default value:
true
Did you try to set it to false?

Comment: That works, great! If you want, post this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consumeAutoHidingEvents

public final BooleanProperty consumeAutoHidingEventsProperty

Specifies whether the event, which caused the Popup to hide, should be consumed. Having the event consumed prevents it from triggering some additional UI response in the Popup's owner window.

Default value: true

Did you try to set it to false?

In common case, all popups can consume event to close inself.